Store refresh token securely with a biometric authentication
I am building a Mobile app that uses Identity server for login cycle, after a successful login from the user, I want to store user's refresh token for future logins to be able to login with his biometric, the issue I am facing is my access token lifetime is 900 seconds (15 minutes) and refresh token is 1 year.
I created a keyStore with biometricAuthenticationRequired flag
first Issue I faced is a biometric authentication is required for every transaction on keyStore entry I created, so I added setAuthenticationParameters(timeout: 900, flags: BIOMETRIC_STRONG) so this keyChain entry will request a biometric every 15 minutes to read/write from it
Issues I faced further:

When the app is killed & device is locked, If the user unlocked the device and within 15 minutes (keyStore timeout duration) opened the app and pressed "Login with Biometric", he will not be prompted to authenticate with his biometric!!
When the user use the app for over 15 minutes (keyStore timeout duration), I have the refresh token in memory, renewed his session, got the new refresh token & wants to write it to my secure storage, he will be prompted for a biometric while he is using the app and not expecting to have a fingerprint popup in his face!

So I am looking for the best practices in storing the refresh token securely behind a biometric with a good UX
Note: Applying a (biometric layer) is not an option because Biometric auth returns a Cipher which is used in the encryption & decryption of the refresh token
